# Skew an image column/div in an inline row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

There are a few answers out there about how to skew the single side of a div both empty and with images:

[CSS3 Transform Skew One Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761202/css3-transform-skew-one-side)

[Skew one side only of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803277/skew-one-side-only-of-an-element)

But using these answers, I cannot figure out the rest of my issue.
I am attempting to create a 2 column row with an image background for the second column and a skewed or angled left side. The problem I have is filling the space with the containers after they have been skewed.

I am using Foundation 6 as the primary framework behind my site.
I have attached an image of how it should look completed[image]

The closest I have got so far is this:[image]

I have posted the code I have so far below.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoEXQb)

HTML:

```
<section class="lan_primary">
  <div class="container-full">
    <div class="row wide">
      <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 lan_primary--select">
        CONTENT LEFT
      </div>
      <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 lan_primary--img">
        CONTENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.lan_primary {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    .row {
        flex-flow: row !important;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    &--select,
    &--img {
        padding: 100px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    &--select {
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    &--img {
        background-color: blue;
        transform-origin: top left;
        transform: skew(-20deg);
        //margin-left: 80px;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE - from first answer**
Adding a pseudo element to solve causes problems with variable heights. If I were to set `100vh`, it would give a different result to if I were to set `height: 700x;`.
See image below:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *triangle border* trick with a pseudo. With viewport units it will scale with the height

To make the *skew* centered, I sized the `right` 25px (half of the skewed 
 area) wider than the left.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 25px);
  position: relative;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.left::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 100vh solid lightgray;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}

.right {
  flex-basis: calc(50% + 25px);
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500/people/10/) left center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"> 
    <h1>Some text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can Make use of the pseudo elements to make the look skewed one side

CSS(SCSS)

```
div {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.lan_primary {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    .row {
        flex-flow: row !important;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    &--select,
    &--img {
        padding: 100px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    &--select {
        background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
    overflow:visible;
    &::after{
      content:"";
      position: absolute;
      z-index:1;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      height:100%;
      width:20%;
      background-color: cyan;
      right:-40px;
      transform:skew(-20deg);
    }
    }
    &--img {
        background-color: blue;
        transform-origin: top left;
        //margin-left: 80px;
    }
}
```

[link for reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/GEMBZR)

hope this helps

Comment: The problem I have found from this solution is that it doesn't really account for height. If I wanted to go 100vh in the row, it would cause some issues. I have updated my answer to show you what I mean