# Unskewing the ends of an assortment multiple skewed images

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287110/5-images-symmetrically-seperated-with-diagonal-lines/49287285#49287285) earlier asking how to skew an assortment of images. I was able to get very satisfying results

[image]

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 215px;
  margin: 30px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.box1 {
  font-size: initial;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box2 {
  font-size: initial;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  height: 100%;
  border: 2.5px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box3 {
  font-size: initial;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  height: 100%;
  border: 2.5px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box4 {
  font-size: initial;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  height: 100%;
  border: 2.5px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box5 {
  font-size: initial;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  height: 100%;
  border: 2.5px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box6 {
  font-size: initial;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  height: 100%;
  border: 2.5px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box1 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box2 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box3 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box4 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -35%;
  right: -35%;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box5 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box6 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -35%;
  right: -35%;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"><span style="background-image:url(illustris1.png)"></span></div>
  <div class="box2"><span style="background-image:url(gal.png)"></span></div>
  <div class="box3"><span style="background-image:url(laniakea.jpg)"></span> </div>
  <div class="box4"><span style="background-image:url(globularstar.jpg)"></span></div>
  <div class="box5"><span style="background-image:url(elliptical.jpg)"></span></div>
  <div class="box6"><span style="background-image:url(illustris2.png)"></span></div>
  <div class="container mid"></div>
</div>
```

While my this snipped of code is lengthy compared to the answered one from the other thread, it allows me to resize for each picture I input.

What I am trying to do now is to have the far left end `box1` and the far right end `box6` of this `container` environment to skewed only in the inner portion of this assortment. It is kind of like the result this poster is wanting to get: [Skew one side only of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803277/skew-one-side-only-of-an-element).

I have been attempting several methods of this for a couple hours and I do not to seem to have luck altering `box1` and `box6` To have one side skewed while not warping the images.

Answer (score 3):

**New answer**

Here is a better version from an article I wrote: https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-and-custom-shapes-part-2/

You can have hover effect and gap as well

```css
.gallery {
  --s: 50px; /* control the slanted part */
  
  display: grid;
  height: 350px;
  gap: 8px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  place-items: center;
}
.gallery > img {
  width: 0;
  min-width: calc(100% + var(--s));
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(var(--s) 0,100% 0,calc(100% - var(--s)) 100%,0 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}
.gallery > img:hover {
  width: 15vw; 
}
.gallery > img:first-child {
  min-width: calc(100% + var(--s)/2);
  place-self: start;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0,calc(100% - var(--s)) 100%,0 100%);
}
.gallery > img:last-child {
  min-width: calc(100% + var(--s)/2);
  place-self: end;
  clip-path: polygon(var(--s) 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  background: #ECD078;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/433/600/400" alt="A Bear">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/582/600/400" alt="A wolf">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/600/400" alt="A lioness">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/600/400" alt="A Dog">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/659/600/400" alt="A kind wolf">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/593/600/400" alt="A Tiger">
</div>
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use negative margin for last and first one to hide half the element:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box:first-child {
  margin-left:calc((100% / 5) / -2);
}
.box:last-child {
  margin-right:calc((100% / 5) / -2);
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  background-image: var(--i);
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="--i:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--i:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/300/)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--i:url(https://lorempixel.com/300/200/)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--i:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/300/)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--i:url(https://lorempixel.com/200/300/)"></div>
</div>
```