# Get two elements next to one another to overlap

Tags: css

I'd like the following result:
[image]

It is two images, that overlap.

I got quite close achieving this with a table and padding like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <table border="1">
    <tr> 
      <th width=500px>
        <div align="center">    
          <img
               src="./img/img_codemesomething.png"
               style="padding-left:100px"
               width=100% />    
        </div>
      </th> 
      <td width=500px>
        <div align="justify">       
          <img
               src="./img/img_recordmesomething.png"
               style="padding-right:100px"
               width=100% />    
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, the result is that either both become very small. Or the left one starts to become bigger than the right one. I tried to use padding on both images then (left and right) but padding-right does nothing while padding-left pushes the images to the right which means it isnt centered anymore.

This is what this looks like:

[image]

(ignore the borders).

If id like the result as shown in the first picture. and have this be exactly centered in width and height in the browser - how would I go on about this?

Thank you:)

*** EDIT:

The Css is nothing but:

```
.container{
    width:900px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

*** EDIT 2: Okay, so I got pretty close. Only problem now is that everything is sort of shifted to the right and not centered anymore but here is what I did:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centered">
                    <table border="0" width=1400px>
                    <tr> 
                        <td width=500px height=400px>
                            <div>   
                                <img
                                    src="./img/img_codemesomething.png"
                                    style="padding-left:40"
                                    width=210%
                                    height=210%
                                </img>  
                            </div>
                        </td>   
                        <td width=500px height=400px>
                            <div>       
                                <img
                                    src="./img/img_recordmesomething.png"
                                    width=210%
                                    height=210%
                                </img>  
                            </div>
                        </td>   

                </table>
    </div>          
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container{
    width:900px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Result:

[image]

I try to get it to sit centered but I will check on other solution as well. So keep em coming :)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or share the code you have used to achieve what you got as if now so that we can check and help you as per your requirement?

Comment: @AKNair maybe somethign is wrong here. the code is posted in the question? cant you see it?

Comment: What I meant is the CSS properties used for the layout using which you acheived this. Here is the fiddle I made with the code you posted. I am not getting the layout which you shared in question: http://jsfiddle.net/dsy5gn7q/1/

Comment: @AKNair see update. it is not really much in there tho...

Comment: @innomotionmedia can you post the links to original images, and also are you anyway restricted to use only tables?

Comment: Best solution IMO would be to use a single image as the background and utilise the [map element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).

Comment: @JamesCoyle it is indeed an idea, however when I hover above one of the images, I want it to increase its size just a little bit more- so with mapping that wouldnt work...

Comment: You can check this link for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361690/two-images-background-inline-separate-by-diagonal-border

Comment: These are the images: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0cfd21ac0b9d1634923829bdbeeb76e020190411115902/bc3efc

Comment: Validate your HTML. You are using a number of obsolete attributes and, in fact, some of your HTML is thoroughly invalid by itself. Note: the `<img>` tag does not need and does not use a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution as per your requirement, you can use image instead of color.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="traingle">
      <div class="triangle-left">
        <p>Code me something</p>
      </div>
      <div class="triangle-right">
        <p>Record me something</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css goes here

```
.traingle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 620px;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.triangle-left {
    width: 300px;
    border-top: solid 180px rgb(200,30,50);
    border-left: solid 0px transparent;
    border-right: solid 180px #00000000;
    margin-right: -156px;
  }
  .triangle-right {
    width: 300px;
    border-top: solid 0px rgb(200,30,50);
    border-left: solid 180px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 180px rgb(200,30,50);
  }
   .traingle p{
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
   }

 .traingle .triangle-left p{
    top: 0px;
    left: 20px;
}
.traingle .triangle-right p{
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

[image: Required Output]

[Refer Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/rajeshkumarsah/pen/MRooOz)

Comment: hey. this does look really good. However, I wasnt able to implement a link (a) to both. I was able to implemend one to one triangle but not the other one. Would you mind showing this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this based on the dimensions of the actual images. The values 59% and 70% are calculated based on image dimensions.

```
<style>
    .container {
        position: relative;
        /**
         * As we are using absolutely positioned elements, parent element's height will not consider them
         * If you want to use this component inside normal flow of the document, that would mess things up.
         * So to make sure that component occupies the height of its children
         * Calculated as 70 * 59 / 100
         */
        padding-top: 41.3%;
    }
    .imageContainer {
        /**
         * Calculated as (W + W - S) / 2 - G
         * (200 - 100 * (slope.width / image.width)) / 2 - gap
         * Here slope.width / image.width = 0.58
         */
        width: 70%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    .psuedoContainer {
        position: relative;
        /**
         * To make sure that image always follows the aspect ratio,
         * even if the container width changes.
         * Calculated as 100 * (image.height / image.width) 
         */
        padding-top: 59%;
    }
    .psuedoHolder {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    img {
       height: 100%;
       width: auto; 
    }
</style>

<div class="component">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="imageContainer" style="left: 0;">
            <div class="psuedoContainer">
                <div class="psuedoHolder" style="text-align: left;">  
                    <img src="./img_codemesomething.png" />  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageContainer" style="right: 0;">
            <div class="psuedoContainer">
                <div class="psuedoHolder" style="text-align: right;">
                    <img src="./img_recordmesomething.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **PS:** You can change the width of the `.component` and everything else will follow the suite and you can position `.component` wherever you want

Comment: interesseting. however, the result is just two images not overlapping :(

Comment: can you explan what's happening or if you can give me the urls of the images you are using, I should be able to give you better solution

Comment: it is just as if the images were to be sitting next to one another but are not overlapping. these are the images I am using. I am excited to see what you are coming up with :) https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0cfd21ac0b9d1634923829bdbeeb76e020190411115902/bc3efc

Comment: I am not able to achieve this using table, the percentage value on img are not following the container width because of table, i am gonna implement this using divs instead

Comment: Very awesome new way of doing this. However one minor flaw: I am not able to implement a link to both images. Adding A HREF only works on the right triangle, not on the left one. Would you mind showing me how to add a link to both? Thank you so much!