# cover fit the inner image of slant div

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I need to create a slope/angled element, so I tried `skew()` transform. Inside this element I have an image which I want to cover the whole area of parent element, but when I applied `skew()` to image to make it straight, the image is not fully covered. I know I can use `scale()` transform to cover the image but thats blur my image. What I am looking for is below image.

[image]

Is there any another way to do this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -30px;
}

.container a {
  border: 3px solid;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  width: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
  <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
  <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
  <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
  <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest and fastest way IMHO is just to scale it, e.g. `scale(1.25)`.

Comment: another duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289529/unskewing-the-ends-of-an-assortment-multiple-skewed-images/49289555#49289555

Answer (score -1):

You can try making the image a bit bigger than its original size with transform: scale() property. Try this code.

```
.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transform: skew(30deg), scale(1.2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use clip-path to mask the images.

Clip Path Generator:
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Caniuse:
https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Browser support is a problem for IE though.

You need to set negative margins (or something similar) on the `<a>` to have the elements align like in your sketch.