# The svg icon is overlapped with backround

Tags: html, css, svg, markup

I've a working skewed div block with icons and text underneath of it. Firstly the `jpeg` icons were used. But they should be swapped with `svg`. Also, icons and text should be always centered. This wasn't achieved with old revision.

I've swapped the icons with `SVG`, changed the markup and `css`, but the icons don't show up. It seems, that they are overlapped by background. Additionally,  some minor problems revealed: text can't be formatted and centered. svg doesn't change the color on `hover`.

here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2v3nrt8/) with `svg` **updated**

And here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: here is an idea with less of code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49289555/8620333 ... it should be easier since you don't have background, or use the icons as background

Comment: You wrap the `<svg>` elements in a `<g>` element. Please change this. It's an error

Comment: As I understand, the `<text>` should be wrapped in `g` tag. So, it should be done in such a way? `<div>     
 <svg>    
  <path/>
  <g>
   <text>xxx</text>
  </g>
 </svg>     
</div>    `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement adaptability, all elements of the site header: the form of sections, icons, text are placed inside the SVG

The form of sections is drawn in the vector editor.

```html
<div class="header">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 671 208" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  

  <path id="p1" fill="#65C6CC"  d="M 5,3 H 150 L 120,203 H 5 Z" />  
   <path id="p2" fill="#E0AD51" d="M 150,3 H 285 L 255,203 H 120 Z" /> 
    <path  id="p3" fill="#329FA4"  d="M 285,3 H 425 L 390,203 H 255 Z" />  
     <path id="p4" fill="#E0AD51"  d="M 425,3 H 560 L 525,203 H 390 L 425,3"/>  
   <path  id="p5" fill="#65C6CC"  d="M 560,3 H 670 V 203 H 525 Z" /> 
  </svg> 
</div>
```

- Add code to icons
- Added text and align it to the center of the section with the command
  `text-anchor="middle"`
- Highlighting the icon and text is implemented using the rules `CSS`

```css
.header {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 
 }
  svg text {
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  fill:white;
  text-anchor:middle;
  }
  :hover.icon {
   fill:greenyellow;
   stroke:greenyellow;
     }
```

```html
<div class="header">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 671 208" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
<g class="icon">
    <path id="p1" fill="#65C6CC"  d="M 5,3 H 150 L 120,203 H 5 Z" />  
  <!-- icon supervisor --> 
   <path class="icon" transform="translate(50 50)" fill="white"  d="M33 24c2.76 0 4.98-2.24 4.98-5s-2.22-5-4.98-5c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5s2.24 5 5 5zm-15-2c3.31 0 5.98-2.69 5.98-6s-2.67-6-5.98-6c-3.31 0-6 2.69-6 6s2.69 6 6 6zm15 6c-3.67 0-11 1.84-11 5.5V38h22v-4.5c0-3.66-7.33-5.5-11-5.5zm-15-2c-4.67 0-14 2.34-14 7v5h14v-4.5c0-1.7.67-4.67 4.74-6.94C21 26.19 19.31 26 18 26z"/>  
   <text x="70" y="130" > MEET
    <tspan x="65" y="150"> THE CREATERS </tspan>
   </text>    
</g>  
 <g class="icon">
   <path id="p2" fill="#E0AD51" d="M 150,3 H 285 L 255,203 H 120 Z" /> 
      <!-- icon alarm -->   
   <path transform="translate(180 50)" fill="white"  d="M44 11.44l-9.19-7.71-2.57 3.06 9.19 7.71L44 11.44zM15.76 6.78l-2.57-3.06L4 11.43l2.57 3.06 9.19-7.71zM25 16h-3v12l9.49 5.71L33 31.24l-8-4.74V16zm-1.01-8C14.04 8 6 16.06 6 26s8.04 18 17.99 18S42 35.94 42 26 33.94 8 23.99 8zM24 40c-7.73 0-14-6.27-14-14s6.27-14 14-14 14 6.27 14 14-6.26 14-14 14z"/> 
 <text x="200" y="130" > CARS THAT
    <tspan x="195" y="150"> FOUND HOMES </tspan>
   </text>      
  </g>   
<g class="icon">  
<path  id="p3" fill="#329FA4"  d="M 285,3 H 425 L 390,203 H 255 Z" />  
     <!-- icon favorite --> 
   <path  transform="translate(310 50)" fill="white" d="M33 6c-3.48 0-6.82 1.62-9 4.17C21.82 7.62 18.48 6 15 6 8.83 6 4 10.83 4 17c0 7.55 6.8 13.72 17.1 23.07L24 42.7l2.9-2.63C37.2 30.72 44 24.55 44 17c0-6.17-4.83-11-11-11zm-8.79 31.11l-.21.19-.21-.19C14.28 28.48 8 22.78 8 17c0-3.99 3.01-7 7-7 3.08 0 6.08 1.99 7.13 4.72h3.73C26.92 11.99 29.92 10 33 10c3.99 0 7 3.01 7 7 0 5.78-6.28 11.48-15.79 20.11z"/> 
     <text x="330" y="130" > CHECK OUT
    <tspan x="325" y="150"> THE `A` LIST </tspan>
   </text> 
  </g> 
<g class="icon">    
<path id="p4" fill="#E0AD51"  d="M 425,3 H 560 L 525,203 H 390 L 425,3"/>  
     <!-- icon map -->
   <path  transform=" scale(2) translate(230 25)" fill="white" d="M20.5 3l-.16.03L15 5.1 9 3 3.36 4.9c-.21.07-.36.25-.36.48V20.5c0 .28.22.5.5.5l.16-.03L9 18.9l6 2.1 5.64-1.9c.21-.07.36-.25.36-.48V3.5c0-.28-.22-.5-.5-.5zM15 19l-6-2.11V5l6 2.11V19z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
 <text x="470" y="130" > DRIVE INTO
    <tspan x="465" y="150"> THE ADVENTURE </tspan>
   </text>  
</g> 
<g class="icon"> 
 <path  id="p5" fill="#65C6CC"  d="M 560,3 H 670 V 203 H 525 Z" /> 
       <!-- chat --> 
    <path  transform="translate(585 50)" fill="white" d="M40 4H8C5.79 4 4.02 5.79 4.02 8L4 44l8-8h28c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4V8c0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4zm-4 24H12v-4h24v4zm0-6H12v-4h24v4zm0-6H12v-4h24v4z"/> 
   <text x="605" y="130" > GET IN TOUCH
       <tspan x="605" y="150"> WITH US </tspan>
      </text> 
</g> 
  </svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Tell me please, how to control the icon `path` size?  I need to set icons sizes: `width="50" height="41`

Comment: <path transform="scale(1.2) translate(X Y)" ..... />   Select the values of the scale () and position the icons translate (X Y)

Comment: ahh.. could you please help with the last issue, I'm unable to reveal an image on hover, as I did it here `https://jsfiddle.net/b2v3nrt8/`  And here is the problem: `https://jsfiddle.net/voftax5q/` I've changed the `img` into `image` tag. But it seems that another technique should be used

Comment: @Kuzma I could not find the reason for the refusal. Since my hobby is svg, but not `CSS` And what you are not satisfied with my decision? After all, it is completely finished and can be embedded anywhere in your HTML page as a separate block.  If you have replaced something and the application is not working, then you can ask a new question. There are a lot of CSS and SVG professionals here and they will definitely find the reason for the rejection.

Comment: No, no, I'm not refusing. I've accepted your answer and it's brilliant! I just want to slightly change the `markup` and `css` in order to make a hover effect work... It's not a problem, I will ask a new question. You have solved my initial problem ;)