# Is there a way to fit paralelogram divs on full page width and same row?

Tags: html, css

I stumbled across this problem and it's giving me a headache for 2 days now. the thing is i am trying to get this look:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrHf4.jpg

But what i got so far is this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo2ng.jpg

So the thing is i want to fit the paralelograms as in the first pictures. with straight edges and on the same line. I tried to make them bigger so they will fit out of the window and get the straight edges but they just got stacked one above another.

So the thing is i want to fit the paralelograms as in the first pictures. with straight edges and on the same line. I tried to make them bigger so they will fit out of the window and get the straight edges but they just got stacked one above another.

I couldn't manage to paste the code here but here is the pastebin:

pastebin.com/Cu5eA45a

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49289555/8620333